# Apache proxy wrong browser url

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, tomcat, virtualhost, tomcat7

I am using the following `VirtualHost` and mod_proxy to proxy all requests for my 'api' subdomain to my Java webservice which is located at `webapps/webservice` on my Tomcat.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.mydoamin.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /webservice http://localhost:8080
    ProxPassReverse / http://localhost:8080
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is if I type 'api.mydomain.com' I get redirected to 'api.mydomain.com/webservice' and I get a 404 error because "webservicewebservice" is not available.

Does anybody know what to do?

**Solution:**
Even though I've tried this solution before, Stony was right! The problem in my case was that, even if I hadn't changed anything there, I had to restart Tomcat to make it working. I restarted Apache multiple times but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing and many many errors, I finally came up with the following solution.

I set up my apache virtual host like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny, allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>                                                                        
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    ServerName api.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now it just proxies all requests for `api.mydomain.com` to my Tomcat on port 8080 without pointing to a specific directory.

Then I added this to `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml`:

```
<Host name="api.mydomain.com" appBase="webapps">
    <Context path="" docBase="webservice" />
</Host>
```

As `ProxyPreserveHost` is activated in my Apache virtual host Tomcat gets the host name of the original request and is able to decide itself which content to deliver.

With `appBase="webapps"` the content seems to be delivered from the root directory, even if its located somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your problem correctly but if you don't want the `webservice` in your URL. Then set your Proxy Pass to `/`.

```
<VirtualHost *::80>
    ServerName api.mydoamin.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/webservice/
    ProxPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/webservice/
</VirtualHost>
```

Or do you want to run your webservice under that domain? And you don't want the redirect?

Comment: I want to run my webservices under the address 'api.mydomain.com' but when I enter this address in my browser it "redirects" me to 'api.mydomain.com/webservices' and I don't want this "redirect"..

Comment: Just that you get me correctly my webservice project is not located at the root path of my Tomcat it's in a subdirectory called 'webservice'

Comment: Then proxy your traffic directly to the correct url `http://localhost:8080/webservice`. Then you should Proxy all from `/` to `/webservice` of your Tomcat.